# Microsoft Report Viewer Control & Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Can the Microsoft Report Viewer control render and display Crystal reports or is it just intended to render SSRS reports?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only renders SSRS reports.  If you want to show both, you'll have to use Crystal's viewer separately.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought was the case.

Answer (score 0):

For rpt(CR) files you need to use Crystal Report Viewer